# Redshift: How to remove non-printable characters

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, non-printing-characters

I'm trying to remove non-printable characters from a string in Redshift and tried the TRANSLATE function but didn't return the results I'm looking for. Any advice?

Comment: OP is correct in that TRANSLATE only does a specified character at a time - not very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite right, this works:

```
regexp_replace(<col>, '[^[:alnum:][:blank:][:punct:]]', '')
```

It's a positive filter that will only allow ASCII, letters, numbers, spaces and punctuation.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a regexp I've used to get down to just the chars:

```
regexp_replace(<col>,'[^[:print:]]|[[:cntrl:]]|[[:blank:]]','')
```

Don't know if this is what you are looking for but a place to start.